# Is magja compatible with Magento 1.7

Tags: java, magento, magento-1.7

Is Magja compatible with Magento 1.7 ?

There is another library to integrate Magento with java?

Comment: I gave up using magja. Now I'm using Axis with the magento API v2. I have generated the java code with the WSDL2Code tool. It's very simple and works fine! See http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2Java:_Building_stubs_skeletons_and_data_types_from_WSDL for more details...

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is compatible with 1.7 but for me it did not work with magento api v2. It works with v1 api of magento.

```
http://magentosite/index.php/api/?wsdl
```

Answer (score 1):

it is compatible, but it has a number of bugs and the development process stopped a long time ago.